# How to protect API from from malicious usage

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

We are developing a community portal service using Java-Spring and Angular UI.  We are also going to have an Android app soon.  Our back-end exposes many services via REST API. There are couple of services which allows anonymous posting and creating service requests.

Here are our questions:

- How can we protect API from DDoS-like attacks? Can we do IP whitelisting or put a cap on requests per minute for certain set of APIs?
- How can we log such malicious requests?

Comment: "anonymous posting/create service requests." seems evil. "Can we do IP white listing" => Yes, you can inject HttpServletRequest in your controller methods and do what you want with it. "put cap on requests per min" => I asked myself the same question. Did not find any pre-implemented solution but it also seems quite easy to do.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I know its evil.. but its public/govt website, where any community member can post report without revealing herself.  We also cant enforce account registration..

Comment: If the service has to allow anonymous posting then there's not much you can do about someone deciding to make malicious requests. However in terms of DDoS protection you'll want the requests running through a proxy, and have the proxy limit the number of requests per minute so it takes the performance hits and not your server. Then in terms of logging you just note the IP making too many requests, perhaps blacklisting it if its a real problem

Comment: use Oauth 2 for protecting from attacks

Comment: The first D in DDoS stands for distributed. This means that blocking a certain IP will not protect you. Some proxies are able to protect you from the most basic DoS attacks like SYN flooding. But basically all you can do is damage mitigation.

Comment: @ma_dev_15 How is adding authorization to an endpoint that cannot enforce authorization a solution?

Comment: You could also have nice answers if you asked such a question on [Information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks @SergeBallesta i will post it there